# How to copy template into slide from another PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to use a template that's used in a separate PowerPoint on a PowerPoint that's made using vba (I'll refer to the one vba makes as "this:).

The way I was doing it was getting the custom layout from the slide master in the template PowerPoint and setting it equal to this PowerPoint custom layout.

What was happening was that it looked like this PowerPoint was completely relying on the template in the template PowerPoint ( I guess it was a direct reference). When I closed that one it also closed this PowerPoint. How do I copy a template (custom layout) into another PowerPoint so it's not a direct reference and relying on template slide to constantly be open

Comment: To get a VBA answer, please post your current code for the sub that creates the PowerPoint file.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a slide master (and all its associated layouts) you like from one presentation into another.

**Copy the slide master from the first presentation**

1. Open both presentations: the one you want to copy a slide master from, and the one you want to paste the slide master into.
2. In the presentation that has the slide master, you want to copy, on the **View** tab, select **Slide Master**.
3. In the slide thumbnail pane, right-click the slide master, and then select **Copy**.

**Paste the slide master into the new presentation**

1. On the **View** tab, select **Switch Windows**, and then select the presentation that you want to paste the slide master to.
2. On the View tab, select **Slide Master**.
3. In the thumbnail pane, right-click the slide master, and then do one of the following;

3.1. To take on the theme colours, fonts, and effects of the destination presentation that you are pasting to, click **Use Destination Theme**.

3.2. To maintain the theme colours, fonts, and effects of the presentation that you are copying from, click **Keep Source Formatting**.

4. When you're finished, select **Close Master View**.

--

Follow the instructions with pictures given [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-and-paste-a-slide-master-from-one-presentation-to-another-ab99cf07-3a65-4f50-9d24-f17444a3df9b).